# Repository Test runs in isolation but fails overall (mvn test)

Tags: maven, unit-testing, spring-boot, flyway

When I run test cases for a UserRepository, it runs in isolation (say, `mvn test -Dtest=UserRepository.class`).

But when I run `mvn test`, it fails.
I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

My test class is as:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class UserRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

// This validates the Hibernate Constraints
private Validator validator;
```

A sample test case is:

```
@Test
public void repo_should_create_a_user() {
    User u = new User();
    u.setUserName("firstUser");
    u.setRole(User.Role.USER);
    entityManager.persist(u);

    User user = userRepository.findAll().get(0);
    Assert.assertThat( user, instanceOf(User.class) );
    assertEquals("firstUser", user.getUserName());

}
```

The `User` entity has regular properties like email and password, and so forth. Also, it contains auditing features like `created_by` and `modified_by` which makes use of the security context to fetch the current user.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please full log message...the context is important...

Answer (score 1):

One of the possibilities is that when different tests are run, the later tests get the database in a dirty state after the first test, so if the `UserRepositoryTest` runs after other tests, they might leave some garbage in the database.

In general, the best is to make sure that there is no 'garbage' data in the database.

One way is to use `@Transactional` annotation on tests so that if everything is integrated correctly, the data that was changed during the tests will be automatically removed from db after the test because Spring will rollback the transaction.

That will guarantee that the next step won't get that garbage.

Comment: Makes absolute sense. But from the logs I can see that the operations were rolled back once completed without the @Transactional annotation. Is it that Spring Boot auto configures this?

Comment: I haven't worked with JPA (we use spring with JOOQ instead) so in my case @Transactional is mandatory and it should be placed on all the tests. I think it will behave the same with JPA as well. Anyway, you can add a couple of "select"-s right into the failing test to check that the "unexpected" data is indeed in the database, probably by the nature of data you'll understand where does it come from exactly.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I use using database auditing properties in my User class, and `created_by` and `modified_by` properties in the `User` class makes use of `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` to fetch the current user.

I added the `@WithMockUser` to the test method and it started to work. I don't exactly know how the independent class only or method only test cases worked, and overall test failed. But adding this annotation apparently makes everyone happy.